# How to enter numbers to a collection in R with loop

Tags: r, loops

I was try to enter 9 numbers to a collection and then print the sum of the collection, new to R programming. But some thing is wrong with the code, I couldn't get the right result.

```
homescore <- c()

for (homescore in 1:9) {
  score <- readline(prompt = "Enter Score: ")
  homescore <- append(homescore,score)
  homescore <- as.numeric(homescore)
}
```

Comment: *"some thing is wrong with the code"* ... what, exactly? Is there an error? warning? Please include the text verbatim (by editing your question).

Comment: When you say `for (homescore in 1:9)`, your loop will set `homescore <- 1` at the start of the first iteration, `homescore <- 2` at the start of the second iteration, etc. Just use `for (i in 1:9)` instead.

Comment: Gregor's explanation is correct.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you say `for (homescore in 1:9)`, your loop will set `homescore <- 1` at the start of the first iteration, `homescore <- 2` at the start of the second iteration, etc. Just use `for (i in 1:9)` instead.

```
# works:
homescore <- c()
for (i in 1:9) {
  score <- readline(prompt = "Enter Score: ")
  homescore <- append(homescore,score)
  homescore <- as.numeric(homescore)
}

# better - convert the input *before* adding it to your vector
# this way we don't risk converting the whole vector back and forth
homescore <- c()
for (i in 1:9) {
  score <- readline(prompt = "Enter Score: ")
  homescore <- append(homescore, as.numeric(score))
}

# much better - pre-allocate homescore instead of "growing" it each time
# change the loop to be get the length from the pre-allocated vector
homescore <- numeric(9)
for (i in seq_along(homescore)) {
  score <- readline(prompt = "Enter Score: ")
  homescore[i] <- as.numeric(homescore)
}
```